# Get width of a child of the parent element that has position absolute

Tags: html, css, dom

Allowing child elements to expand based on how long the text is to have their own width and not be limited by parents' width limitations as you see in this image attached. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ0JN.png

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li>
    <span>Solutions</span>
    <div class="sub-cont">
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a href="#">New Seller Suite</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pro Seller Suite</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Advanced Seller Suite</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Assisted Seller Suite</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Managed Seller Suite</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>


 ul#nav {
  display: flex;
  > li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 28px;

    .sub-cont {
      height: 0%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;
      left: -20px;
      width: 100%;

      ul.sub-nav {
        padding: 20px 20px 12px 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
        transform: translateY(5px);
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        /* autoprefixer: off */
        transition-property: opacity, transform, visibility;
        transition-duration: 600ms, 900ms, 300ms;
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1),
        cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), linear;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: with the css and html you gave me i cant reproduce it. Click on the question click on the `<>`   and add html and css , otherwise none will be able to help, because i don't know what your code does

Comment: or produce it here https://jsfiddle.net/ and give the link

Comment: Tried jsfiddle get 502 Bad Gateway when I run it.

Comment: try https://jsbin.com/

Comment: Still fails https://jsbin.com/cucumezala/edit?html,css,output

Comment: if you can't even produce how can i fix something without seeing it, you may be missing libraries or something you may have added

Answer (score 0):

So the element you want to break out of the parents you can use:
width: auto;
white-space: nowrap; <<--- This is what pushes the container to expands the width of the content